# Using option flag with condition (shell script)

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, phpunit

I have this command inside my shell script file:

```
docker exec dev-wordpress $phpunitPath \
  --configuration $configurationPath \
  --testsuit $testsuit \
  --group $group \
  --testdox
```

It is working if I set the 'testsuit' and the 'group' as command line options.
The 'testsuit' and 'group' options should be used only if those variables has value.
Same issue with 'testdox' is solved with 'if-else' but it is not a good way when I want to do the same with 3 different options.

**How can I avoid the '--group' option if I don't have value in $group variable?**

```
#!/bin/zsh
phpunit="/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/irea/api/src/vendor/bin/phpunit"
configuration="/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/irea/api/tests/phpunit.xml"
testdox=
filter=
testsuite=
group=

while [ "$1" != "" ]; do
    case $1 in
        --group )       shift
                        group="--group $1"
                        ;;
        --testsuite )   shift
                        testsuite="--testsuite $1"
                        ;;
        --filter )      shift
                        filter="--filter $1"
                        ;;
        --testdox )     testdox="--testdox"
                        ;;
    esac
    shift
done

docker exec irea-wordpress $phpunit \
  --configuration $configuration \
  $testsuite \
  $group \
  $filter \
  $testdox
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to build up the command as a string first then run it with eval.

```
eval "docker exec irea-wordpress $phpunit --configuration $configuration $testsuite $group $filter $testdox"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use parameter expansion :

```
docker exec dev-wordpress "$phpunitPath" \
  --configuration "$configurationPath" \
  ${testsuit:+--testsuit "$testsuit"} \
  ${group:+--group "$group"} \
  --testdox
```

This script should work well for $testsuit and $group.

I didn't notice you may have problem for the other two variable.

I updated the script, maybe you can try again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It doesn't work, but helped me to find the right way. There is one more step (maybe not the best one).
There was an issue right after the '--configuration ...' flag. It was broke into two parts and try to run '--testsuite api' as a separated command.